# How can this sheet be reformatted to be more tabular?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, transpose

Is there a way to take the data from this example and format it in the tabular structure below?

[image: Google Sheets Example]
Google Sheets Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TsN5zDdZlZGVVSuzgwm-u8lQARKLP_0_QPrcMKrV1Ws/edit?usp=sharing

| Priority | ID | Date | Signups |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No Priority | 55001 | 10/13/20 | 1 |
| No Priority | 55001 | 10/14/20 | 6 |
| No Priority | 55001 | 10/15/20 | 3 |
| Low Priority | 55003 | 10/13/20 | 9 |
| Low Priority | 55001 | 10/13/20 | 4 |

Comment: It is best to show a photo of the pivot table in question and not uploading a file.  Many, including me, will not download files from public sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
={"Priority", "ID", "Date", "Signups";
 ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(
 INDIRECT("Sheet1!C3:"& ROWS(Sheet1!C:C))="",,
 INDIRECT("Sheet1!A3:A"&ROWS(Sheet1!C:C))&"×"&
 INDIRECT("Sheet1!B3:B"&ROWS(Sheet1!C:C))&"×"&
 INDIRECT("Sheet1!A2:2")&"×"&
 INDIRECT("Sheet1!C3:"& ROWS(Sheet1!C:C)))), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null format Col3 'dd/mm/yyyy'", 0))}
```

[image]